# dont Post JSON array to mvc controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post JSON to a mvc controller through AJAX. I use this code but it does not do the post.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-success").click(function(e){
        var urData = { City: 'Moscow', Age: 25 };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Category/Create/",  
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType : "application/json",
            data: urData,
            success: function(maindta) {
                alert(maindta);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });
});
```

This is controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult Create(List<object> urData){

}
```

Comment: Why is your parameter `List<object> urData`? You should be posting back your model, not `object`. And what is the data your posting back. If you have correctly generated your view, then its just `data: $('#ajaxform').serialize(),`

Comment: iam edit post am post usdata

Comment: Side note: Your posting and object, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posting back an object with 2 properties so you need a model with those 2 properties

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and the method needs to be changed to

```
public JsonResult Create(MyModel model)
{
   .... // model will be populated with the values you sent
   return Json(...);`
}
```

and you need to remove the following options from the ajax method

```
contentType : "application/json",
traditional: true,
```

Alternatively, you method can be

```
public JsonResult Create(string city, int age)
```

but you lose the benefits of model validation

Side note: Always use the `Url.Action()` method to ensure your url's are correctly generated

```
url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Category")',
```